# Pentaho Microsoft Access Input with multiple files

Tags: ms-access, etl, pentaho

I am using PDI 8.3 and have a collection of Microsoft Access files in a folder. I am using Microsoft Access Input and have a table name chosen. If the table does not actually exist in onw of the files, the transformation stops at that point without any errors and does not continue on to the next file.  For example, if being output to another database (like MS Access Input to mysql):

- file_a.accdb => has the table "dbo_foo"
- file_b.accdb => has the table "dbo_foo"
- file_c.accdb => DOES NOT have the table "dbo_foo"
- file_d.accdb => has the table "dbo_foo"

In this scenario, the transformation will run and data from file_a and file_b will be inserted, but the transformation will stop because the table doesn't exist in file_c. While that might be ok, I still need the data in file_d inserted, and Pentaho is not showing errors for me to even detect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you call list of the access database. But you can use below [PROCESS](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Ce_jI5dolqiQlujwNOT94wlEVrkx-5dK?usp=sharing) , where each database will process individually (even if any one has no table match).

[image]

Comment: I am using a modified version of this (GetFileNames instead of Data grid, and some additional processing in the transformation), but going to use the basic idea nonetheless. Many thanks for your solution! I believe the original issue is possibly a bug. A transformation shouldn't just stop if pulling multiple files and it can't find a table in one of them. At least an error would be useful.